# Question regarding closures? Is this a form of pseudo-closure, if so, why use function closures over this?

Tags: javascript, closures

I am currently learning JS trying to understand closures and their uses. I understand they are useful to avoid polluting the global scope, but then I realised, isn't the code below basically the same as a closure without using a function? I am not sure if I have missed the point of closures so if someone with more knowledge could verify is this is a closure, and if so, why using a function is better.

```js
log = console.log;
dir = console.dir; 
{
  let x = 0;

  function testFunc() {
    log(++x);
  }
}

let func = testFunc;
testFunc();
```

Comment: Closures are used to capture the state of local variables. You're thinking of IIFE (Immediately Executed Function Expression).

Comment: `testFunc()` doesn't return anything, there's no point in assigning it to `func`

Comment: My apologies, I meant = testFunc;

Comment: Then did you mean to call `func()` at the end?

Comment: Yes I meant func(), but I suppose it would have the same effect as just calling it directly? My main point was using a let block to hide variables from the global scope as oppose to functions

Comment: I understand, and my answer answers that.

Comment: `let` is a very recent addition to the language.

Comment: So the code above is essentially the same, except you cannot use var variables? I am asking because all sources on closures talk about functions and not let blocks

Comment: Because most of the time you want to be able to make multiple closures, each with their own captured environment. You're just creating one counter, what if you want to create more of them? You can have a `createCounter()` function, and each time you call it you get a new closure with its own environment.

Comment: Make sure to always use strict mode. With the local scope, `testFunc` is not available outside of the block - you depend on legacy behaviour here. It should be `let func; { let x = 0; func = function() { … }; } func();`

Comment: That is interesting... I never thought about the accessibility of a function call, since you do not declare them with var/let, so, in strict mode they become like a let variable?

Comment: @Barmar `let` is *not* a "very" recent addition to the language, it's been available *for a half dozen years*

Comment: @Dexygen Some browsers, e.g. Safari, have been pertty slow to adopt many ES6 features. And old habits die hard; IIFEs probably aren't going away any time soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're comparing your code with something like this:

```js
log = console.log;

let func = function() {
  let x = 0;

  function increment() {
    log(++x);
  }
  return increment;
}();

func();
func();
```

Your code is indeed equivalent. The older style was used before `let` variable declarations were added to JavaScript in EcmaScript 2015 (AKA EcmaScript 6). That added the ability to create variables that are scoped to a block, rather than a whole function.

If you change your version to use `var x = 0;`, the `x` variable pollutes the global scope.

The other reason that closures are usually inside other functions is so that you can create a dynamic number of them.

```js
function create_counter(start = 0) {
  return function() {
    return start++;
  }
}

counter1 = create_counter();
counter2 = create_counter(5);
console.log(counter1());
console.log(counter1());

console.log(counter2());
console.log(counter2());
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: @MysaMysa should mark this as the correct answer.  At this point, EcmaScript 2015 (AKA ES6) is supported nearly everywhere, aside from a few embedded holdouts (InDesign, etc) that are using older embedded JS engines.

Comment: @Tracker1 I don't understand your edit. Closures weren't added in ES6, `let` and `const` were.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, should have linked to [block scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block#block_scoping_rules_with_let_const_or_function_declaration_in_strict_mode)